# How can I import a file into table?

Tags: mysql, file-io, load, local

I am trying to populate a table with a data in a CSV file

How can I do that correctly?

Here is what I currently have

```
INSERT INTO  time_zones_master (time_zone_id, UTC_Offset, master_name, display_name)
VALUES
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'd:\\UploadFiles/tzids.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: [The Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

Comment: What *problems* do you have currently?

Comment: Show some lines from the CSV file and show CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will face  problem  to match the columns in the CSV file to those in the table.
i suggest to use mySQL clients that have very nice import dialogs for this kind of thing.
one option is Windows based **[HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com)**. there may be a lot , but  am using this :-D

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Desktop\\csvfile.csv' INTO TABLE `database`.`table` CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`);
SHOW WARNINGS;
```